# Bootstrap 4 input field not sending value to server (python, flask, GAE)

Tags: python, flask, bootstrap-4

I can't get an input field in a form to send a value to the server. (I'm using flask + python on Google App Engine).

Please excuse me if this is a rookie question...

```
Part of my html template file:

 <form class="form-inline" action="/rm_list" method="POST">
    <div class="row" >
      <div class="col-span-6">
        <fieldset>
        <input class="form-control form-control-lg" type="text" name="searchtext" placeholder="Product...">
        <input name="text1">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"><i class="material-icons w3-text-black" >search</i></button>
      </div>
      ...
      ...
      some radio buttons
```

So I dumped the POST data to the terminal to debug:

```
my_data = request.form
for key in my_data:
    print ('form key '+key+" "+my_data[key])
```

After trying different solutions, I found that the culprit is the type="text" attribute.
I could see the value of the simple text1 input, but the value from the searchtext input just wasn't in the received data :-(

If I remove "type="text" as follows:

```
<input class="form-control form-control-lg" name="searchtext" Placeholder="Product...">
```

then the searchtext field is received Ok by the server.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems to me that your <input> field is simply missing the value attribute.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your  field is simply missing the value attribute. – Anonymous